# Django:UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id

Tags: python, django

I am using a **Form** to create a registration feature for my website. However, when I try to register, I encounter the following issue. Strangely, in the admin database, a user and profile have been successfully created. Can anyone please help me identify what might be causing this problem

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id
```

model

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid
# Create your models here.
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True , blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    short_intro = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True , null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        null=True, blank=True, upload_to='profiles/', default='profiles/user-default.png')
    social_github = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_website = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, 
                          primary_key=True, editable=False)    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']  
        
class Skill(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, 
                          primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.name)
        
#@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)        
def createProfile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user = instance
        profile = Profile.objects.create(
            user = user,
            username = user.username,
            email = user.email,
            name = user.first_name,
        )  

        
def deleteUser(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    
    try:
        user = instance.user
        user.delete()
    except:
        pass  

post_delete.connect(deleteUser, sender=Profile)
post_save.connect(createProfile, sender=User)
```

views

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, ProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

def loginUser(request):
    page = 'login'
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('profiles')
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username'].lower()
        password = request.POST['password']
        
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'Username does not exit')
        
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('profiles')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')
            
    return render(request, 'users/login_register.html')
    
def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.info(request, 'User was logged out')
    return redirect('login')

def registerUser(request):
    page = 'register'
    form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.clean()
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            user.save()
            
            messages.success(request, 'User account was created!')
            
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('profiles')
            
         
        else:
            messages.success(
                request,'An error has occured during registration')
            
    context = {'page': page, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'users/login_register.html', context)

def profiles(request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()
    context = {'profiles': profiles}
    return render(request, 'users/profiles.html', context)

def userProfile(request, pk):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    
    topSkills = profile.skill_set.exclude(description__exact="")
    otherSkills = profile.skill_set.filter(description="")
    
    context = {'profile': profile, 'topSkills': topSkills, 'otherSkills': otherSkills}
    return render(request, 'users/user-profile.html', context)
    
@login_required(login_url = 'login')    
def userAccount(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    
    skills = profile.skill_set.all()
    projects = profile.project_set.all()
    
    context = {'profile': profile, 'skills': skills, 'projects': projects}
    return render(request,'users/account.html',context)
    
@login_required(login_url = 'login')    
def editAccount(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    form = ProfileForm(instance = profile)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
            return redirect('account') 
            
    context = {'form':form}    
    return render(request, 'users/profile_form.html', context)
```

forms

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']
        labels = {
                'first_name':'Name',
        }        
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})    

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'username', 
        'location', 'bio', 'short_intro', 'profile_image', 'social_github', 
        'social_linkedin', 'social_youtube','social_twitter', 'social_website']
```

signals

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

#@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)        
def createProfile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user = instance
        profile = Profile.objects.create(
            user = user,
            username = user.username,
            email = user.email,
            name = user.first_name,
        )  
        
def updateUser(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    profile = instance
    user = profile.user
    
    if created == False:
        user.first_name = profile.name
        user.username = profile.username
        user.email = profile.email
        user.save()
        
def deleteUser(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    
    try:
        user = instance.user
        user.delete()
    except:
        pass
    
post_save.connect(createProfile, sender=User)
post_save.connect(updateUser, sender=Profile)
post_delete.connect(deleteUser, sender=Profile)
```

I have tried using **form.clean()** and have also conducted several Google searches, but I still can't identify the issue.><